# UIView Greyscale , animation and performance issues

Tags: iphone, animation, sdk, grayscale

I'm developing an app and i'm implementing an application to manage orders some orders of a client.
In this view i have implemented a facebook style menu ( the new one that appears by shifting the whole window right) and i'have added a greyscale effect to the main view when it's shifted to right.
I've accomplished it by creating a UIImage of the current screen and by adding it over the real view and animating it's alpha from 1 to 0
Here's the code i've used to

```
-(void)toggleMenu {
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(self.view.bounds.size);
    [self.view.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
    if (![menu isOpened]){
        UIImage *viewImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
        UIImage *blackAndWhiteImage = [UIImage getBlackAndWhiteVersionOfImage:viewImage];
        overlayImage = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithImage:blackAndWhiteImage];
        overlayImage.alpha = 0.1;
        overlayImage.userInteractionEnabled=NO;
        [self.view addSubview:overlayImage];
    }

    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.3 animations:^{
        CGRect newRect = [self tabBarController].view.frame;
        if (![menu isOpened]){
            newRect.origin.x += 150;
            [menu setOpened:YES];
            overlayImage.alpha = 1.0;
        } else {
            newRect.origin.x -= 150;
            [menu setOpened:NO];
            overlayImage.alpha = 0;
        }
        [self tabBarController].view.frame = newRect;

    } completion:^(BOOL finished){
        if(![menu isOpened]){
            [overlayImage removeFromSuperview];
            overlayImage = nil;
        }
    }];
}
```

The problem is that i'm having issues with performances during animation ( little with iPhone 4 i'm trying an 3gs in next hours... )

Does anyone have any suggestions on what to do to get better performances ? 
Regards

```
+ (UIImage *)getBlackAndWhiteVersionOfImage:(UIImage *)anImage {
UIImage *newImage;

if (anImage) {
    CGColorSpaceRef colorSapce = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceGray();
    CGContextRef context = CGBitmapContextCreate(nil, anImage.size.width * anImage.scale, anImage.size.height * anImage.scale, 8, anImage.size.width * anImage.scale, colorSapce, kCGImageAlphaNone);
    CGContextSetInterpolationQuality(context, kCGInterpolationHigh);
    CGContextSetShouldAntialias(context, NO);
    CGContextDrawImage(context, CGRectMake(0, 0, anImage.size.width, anImage.size.height), [anImage CGImage]);

    CGImageRef bwImage = CGBitmapContextCreateImage(context);
    CGContextRelease(context);
    CGColorSpaceRelease(colorSapce);

    UIImage *resultImage = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:bwImage];
    CGImageRelease(bwImage);

    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(anImage.size, NO, anImage.scale);
    [resultImage drawInRect:CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, anImage.size.width, anImage.size.height)];
    newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
}

return newImage;
```

}

Comment: did your client regest support for 3G S? if not then i wouldn't worry about performance on this device it's not produced anymore and is being phased out of being supported by apple. Also there is a major difference in the technical specs between the two devices. If you are getting a small performance hit on the iPhone4 you will get a major performance hit on the iPhone3G S

Comment: You can clearly expect performance issues in between `UIGraphicsBeginImageContext()` and `UIGraphicsEndImageContext()`. Also, `getBlackAndWhiteVersionOfImage:` sounds heavy. Animations look just fine though...

Comment: Edited the main comment i've added the code of getBlackAndWhiteVersionOfImage.

Comment: Ok, one improvement (x3 faster) is to render layer directly into gray context. You do not have to copy those images then.

Comment: Sorry for my noob question... do you talk about changing the getBlackAndWhiteVersionOfImage method for not taking a UIImage as parameter but by automatically use the UIView ?

Answer (score 1):

Making an image of the screen is costly.  I'm not clear exactly what effect you want but I would overlay another view instead or animate a move of the main view instead.

For example, you can overlay a UIView that has a black background but an alpha of 0.1 to grey out a region.

Comment: You can see an [example of what i want to get](http://www.e-tip.net/example.png).